# Swagger Code Gen Generator creating a model which extends array list and spring fox isn't picking it up

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I used swagger code gen to generate models for a REST application.

The JSON representation of the model it should be generating looks like

[ object1, object2, object3 ]

But swagger code gen represents a schema that is just a list of another object as something like this in the code:

```
Things extends ArrayList<thing>
```

Spring fox isn't recognizing this object when it generates the swagger file / api info page.  Something about doing "extends ArrayList" is causing it to be confused.  Writing the swagger file in swagger editor produces a valid model, but the code generated from swagger code gen does not.

I can hand write the model to contain an object that is List and that should resolve the problem, but then my swagger file that I'm using for code generation won't be accurate.

Is there a secret to get this to work properly?  I'm wondering if there's something I should be adding to the Docket to get it to register this properly.

What should my swagger file look like if I'm using swagger code gen to generate code for use in spring fox if the response body for one operation is an array of a single type of object?  (An array of multiple types of objects actually seems to work fine, it's just when it's only a single object that it has problems.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by modifying the schema in the request section to be of type array rather than specifying it in my model declarations and it resolved the issue for JSON responses.  Though the XML response didn't provide useful information (just said a blank xml response will be sent back) but it's fine for me because my project is only using JSON.